Is Gemini Code Assist available yet? I can't see it as an extension in Visual Studio Code
I can see and have installed "Gemini + Google Cloud Code" but can't see the Code Assist extension to install. Has anyone else successfully installed the Code Assist extension? The Gemini chatbot tells me that Gemini Code Assist and Gemini + Google Cloud Code are two different extensions

Your question title and text seem like they're describing different things.  If you can't see the extension, how did you install it?

The Gemini chat tells me that Gemini Code Assist and Gemini + Google Cloud Code are two different extensions

Gemini Code Assist is a feature of Google Cloud Code, install Google Cloud Code and you can point it at a GCP project with the API enabled (assuming your principal has the appropriate roles required)
